# Rewrite url, expression that accept two different words for the same url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm rewriting a url for a bilingual website.

At the moment I need to write the same rule 2 times and the only difference is the language of the category name, 'product' and 'prodotto':

```
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?public=12&n=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^prodotto/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?public=12&n=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Is there a way to write this rule only one time, accepting both cases 'product' for English and 'prodotto' for Italian?

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([prodotto-product])/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?public=12&n=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex alternation to combine it into one:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:prodotto|product)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?public=12&n=$1&a=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Only one thing: should I always use the QSA in the rewrite rules? For what is that?

Comment: `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. So in your case `QSA` is good to have.